# Need help recovering RAID 6 array

Tags: centos, raid, lvm, xfs, raid6

My CentOS 6.5 server had its primary drive fail the other day. Our hosting company replaced the primary drive and reinstalled the OS.  The system is up and running, but the 15TB of RAID6 storage isn't mounting. I need help figuring out how to get it to mount.  My recollection is 95% sure that I formatted this array using XFS because I had some issues getting EXT4 to work.

Drive configuration:

- Bay 0 contains the boot SSD (100GB)
- Bays 1-7 contain 3GB HDs that form a RAID6 array
- RAID controller is LSI MegaRAID SAS 9260-8i

Prior to re-installation, the last mount config was:

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root   50G   12G   36G  24% /
/dev/sdb1                     485M  164M  296M  36% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home   53G  845M   49G   2% /home
/dev/sda1                      14T  4.9T  8.0T  38% /home/gflftp/gflcontent
```

My recollection is that both of the VolGroup mounts were on the old SSD and then I mounted the RAID array on /dev/sda1 into the subdirectory /home/gflftp/gflcontent

When they reinstalled CentOS, I ended up with the following mounts:

```
/dev/sdb2 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sdb1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
```

pvdisplay gives

```
[root@origin ~]# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               vg_origin
  PV Size               13.64 TiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              3576194
  Free PE               2008
  Allocated PE          3574186
  PV UUID               3O08mA-2zL0-2FzY-ERNf-27lw-h9zB-MnjJq4
```

lvdisplay gives

```
[root@origin ~]# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_origin/lv_root
  LV Name                lv_root
  VG Name                vg_origin
  LV UUID                sx3AVu-AiMD-d4se-Fds4-TjzT-Hf3l-qGhRIQ
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time origin.gfl.tv, 2014-01-18 13:52:57 -0800
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_origin/lv_home
  LV Name                lv_home
  VG Name                vg_origin
  LV UUID                cPQSMO-SHp8-KusI-fhdH-mkuQ-Pljy-reHzw2
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time origin.gfl.tv, 2014-01-18 13:53:09 -0800
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                13.59 TiB
  Current LE             3561386
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
```

When I try to mount /dev/vg_origin/lv_home  I get

```
mount -t xfs /dev/vg_origin/lv_home /mnt/tmp
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg_origin-lv_home,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

----- ADDITIONAL INFO -----

As an indicator of whether the data is still on the drive, note from the pre-crash mount log:

```
/dev/sda1  14T  4.9T  8.0T  38% /home/gflftp/gflcontent
```

The current info that pretty closely matches that is:

lsblk

```
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0  13.7T  0 disk 
├─sda1                         8:1    0   500M  0 part 
└─sda2                         8:2    0  13.7T  0 part 
  ├─vg_origin-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  
  └─vg_origin-lv_home (dm-1) 253:1    0  13.6T  0 lvm  
sdb                            8:16   0 111.3G  0 disk 
├─sdb1                         8:17   0  1000M  0 part /boot
├─sdb2                         8:18   0  97.7G  0 part /
└─sdb3                         8:19   0   4.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0                           11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sdc                            8:32   1   3.8G  0 disk 
└─sdc1                         8:33   1   3.8G  0 part
```

Full config info:

```
Adapter #0

Number of Virtual Disks: 2
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-6, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-3
Size                : 13.642 TB
Is VD emulated      : Yes
Parity Size         : 5.457 TB
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 64 KB
Number Of Drives    : 7
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAhead, Cached, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAhead, Cached, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Disk's Default
Encryption Type     : None
Bad Blocks Exist: No
Is VD Cached: No
Number of Spans: 1
Span: 0 - Number of PDs: 7

PD: 0 Information
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 1
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 0
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 9
WWN: 5000c5004e36db2a
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d50a3b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d40a3b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d400000 Sectors]
Emulated Drive: Yes
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: CC4B
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221102000000
Connected Port Number: 3(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1F13ZK9ST3000DM001-9YN166                      CC4B    
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :28C (82.40 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No




PD: 1 Information
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 2
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 1
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 10
WWN: 5000c5004e453922
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d50a3b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d40a3b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d400000 Sectors]
Emulated Drive: Yes
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: CC4B
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221101000000
Connected Port Number: 2(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1F15BG1ST3000DM001-9YN166                      CC4B    
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :28C (82.40 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No




PD: 2 Information
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 4
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 2
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 11
WWN: 5000c5004dfbaef0
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d50a3b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d40a3b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d400000 Sectors]
Emulated Drive: Yes
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: CC4B
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221104000000
Connected Port Number: 4(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1F0XYKAST3000DM001-9YN166                      CC4B    
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :27C (80.60 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No




PD: 3 Information
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 3
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 3
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 12
WWN: 5000c5004dfbb13b
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d50a3b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d40a3b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d400000 Sectors]
Emulated Drive: Yes
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: CC4B
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221100000000
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1F0XYDXST3000DM001-9YN166                      CC4B    
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :28C (82.40 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No




PD: 4 Information
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 6
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 4
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 13
WWN: 5000c5004e2cf658
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d50a3b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d40a3b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d400000 Sectors]
Emulated Drive: Yes
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: CC4B
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221106000000
Connected Port Number: 6(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1F12GNFST3000DM001-9YN166                      CC4B    
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :27C (80.60 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No




PD: 5 Information
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 5
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 5
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 14
WWN: 5000c5004dfbbeef
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d50a3b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d40a3b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d400000 Sectors]
Emulated Drive: Yes
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: CC4B
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221105000000
Connected Port Number: 5(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1F0XTDEST3000DM001-9YN166                      CC4B    
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :26C (78.80 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No




PD: 6 Information
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 7
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 6
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 15
WWN: 5000c5004dfb9e28
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d50a3b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d40a3b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d400000 Sectors]
Emulated Drive: Yes
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: CC4B
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221107000000
Connected Port Number: 7(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1F0XYCBST3000DM001-9YN166                      CC4B    
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :27C (80.60 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Virtual Drive: 1 (Target Id: 1)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-0, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 111.281 GB
Is VD emulated      : No
Parity Size         : 0
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 64 KB
Number Of Drives    : 1
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Enabled
Encryption Type     : None
Bad Blocks Exist: No
Is VD Cached: No
Number of Spans: 1
Span: 0 - Number of PDs: 1

PD: 0 Information
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 0
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 1, Span: 0, Arm: 0
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 8
WWN: 50026b773a02f1b9
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 111.790 GB [0xdf94bb0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 111.290 GB [0xde94bb0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 111.281 GB [0xde90000 Sectors]
Emulated Drive: No
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: BBF1
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221103000000
Connected Port Number: 1(path0) 
Inquiry Data: 50026B773A02F1B9    KINGSTON SV300S37A120G                  505ABBF1
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Solid State Device
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No
```

Any ideas how to get this array mounted?

Comment: Just from a brief look, it _looks_ like they erased your RAID array, and copied the contents of the old primary drive onto it. You need to have a long hard talk with your provider about exactly what they did.

Comment: Stupid question, have you tried `mount` just like that without `-t something` in case the filesystem type was something else?

Comment: There are things missing here, and the non-block-text formatting makes it difficult to read :( .  The first thing to come to mind, does the RAID controller card (usually the weakest link in a RAID setup) still have the correct configuration?  And if so, did you look to see if the kernel device driver for it was loaded correctly?

Comment: Marki - yes, I did try to mount without the type and it asks for the type :(

Comment: Avery and Michael - the RAID controller info looks good and it **appears** that everything is still there. I'll augment the main post with further information. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think your additional information changes anything. Go yell at your hosting provider for destroying your data.

Comment: You could also try `file -s`: `# file -s /dev/mapper/lvm--luks--raid-lvm5
/dev/mapper/lvm--luks--raid-lvm5: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=7b6fbaca-5b34-4818-927f-d90e0fc2ab5d (needs journal recovery) (large files)`

Comment: I'm of the understanding that Seagate drives with a CC4B firmware are recommended to have their firmwares upgraded, especially if in a RAID array. I put one of your serial numbers in here and it did indeed come up with firmware needed/important: https://apps1.seagate.com/downloads/request.html HTH